# Codeigniter subfolder can't access

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a doubt in codeigniter htaccess and please read below.

My demo url : **sampleurl.com** and i have all the files under a subfolder name demo.

`-sampleurl.com
  -demo
      - application
      - system
      - index.php
  -demo1`

I have two subpages ie **sampleurl.com/aboutus**, **sampleurl.com/contactus**

I have another folder demo1 and i cant access this folder, because i have to access through **http://www.sampleurl.com/demo1** -  it shows page not found.

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /demo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Please help me.

Comment: The problem is not on codeigniter since you were not able to access the `index.php` on both `demo` and `demo1` folders. Your `sampleurl.com` root folder should not contain underlying index files or htaccess files that forbids access to the containing folders. Is there any other contents of your `sampleurl.com` root directory other than the two folders?

Comment: no only two folders are present in sampleurl.com

Comment: What are the other files present on sampleurl.com?

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess file?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the content of htaccess file

Comment: `RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: I have codeigniter files under demo and the demo1 folder is having wordpress so i cant able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope that would be work.